# Zoom H6 overdubbing

Tags: zoom-h6

I wonder if I can copy a soundtrack to Zoom H6 so that I can record my voice while hearing that track. The same thing that they do in the studio when recording a song, but just with Zoom H6 without a computer.
I managed to do this in Adobe Audition by using Zoom h6 as audio interface, but I would like to do the same thing without a computer, since it has its own noise.
Is it possible? What should I do for this? (step by step if possible)

Comment: Have you checked page 31 of the manual?
https://zoomcorp.com/media/documents/E_H6.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You just copy the track to Zoom and change the name. But first you need to record the track of the same length (it does not matter that microphone is not connected; you simply press record and record the track of the same length as the track you want to copy to Zoom H6. Then you rename it and then you follow the instructions about overdubbing.